# How to represent repository pattern in UML?

Tags: uml, repository-pattern

How to represent Repository pattern in UML?

Is there any stereotype that can be used to describe repository pattern? I am using Enterprise Architect to create diagrams. I specifically looking for class diagram representation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Martin Fowler, [*P of EAA*, p. 322](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html):

[image: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html]

(However, you *must* have already found this since it's the first hit on Google.)

Based on this example (and the text from P of EAA), this roughly translates to the following DCD:

[image]

Comment: thanks jensgram, yes I found it. But I am looking for class diagram. Sorry I didn't mention it earlier. I have updated the question now.

Comment: @kaps I've tried to draw a DCD. In this, the `Person` is the specific model type we fetch from the repository. The `Benefactor` type is not part of the excerpt of P of EAA available from Google Books so you might need to read up on this type. In all cases, `Client` should hold a reference to the `Benefactor`.

Answer (score 1):

jensgram has already provided an answer on how to represent the pattern as classes.

When it comes to using patterns in EA, you can quite easily create them yourself using Save UML Pattern under the Diagram - Advanced menu. This saves an XML representation of the pattern.

You import the pattern for use in your project either using the Resources window or by creating an MDG Technology (more complex, but a much better alternative for medium and large-scale deployments).

Unfortunately, the one UML diagram type where EA does not support pattern creation is the sequence diagram.